# blender animation node problem. 'render animation' crashed

Tags: animation-nodes, error

I made sound reactive logo animation. And after finished, I clicked 'render animation' and then my blender file is shut down. Viewport render animation was fine. But I use 2.9 version for eevee motion blur, so it was very trouble. I couldnt find the problem about crashing. So can anyone help me about this situation?

My computer
cpu:x3950
gpu:rtx 2080ti
ram:3600 cl18 64gb

blender 2.9
animation node version 2.2.1

I searched about 'shut down' but usually people said it is computer's problem about ram or something.

Do I need more ram..? :(

File is uploaded. I hope this was just my node tree problem... cause of my not enough knowledge about animation node. Please help me artist.

What is the problem!

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NG1B_xxzaX-16WH4FBBNtF2N5yt6q2gj/view?usp=sharing)
[image]

Comment: Does it shutdown imidiately? For me it renders slow but steadily :)

Comment: small tipp: I'd render heavy things like this as png-sequence, because when it crashes you will keep your progress

Comment: @AM I also rendered png-sequence before. But.. It also shut down.. Do you use blender 2.9 version? If so, Is there possibility my other add-on was crashed with animation node?

Comment: sry, ill have to test it again tomorow. best regards :)